# URL serviço RESTful funcionando, mas no ANDROID retorna null

Tags: java, android, rest, restful

Estou tentando desenvolver um serviço rest para loja do meu pai, estou conseguindo trazer os resultados em JSON atraves da URL, porem quando tento executor  o mesmo método no android para tentar preencher o objeto, ele retorna null, já debuguei e consigo ir até o metodo que faz o SELECT no banco, ele traz a lista certa, preenchida.. O problema está no lado do android, nao consigo mapear o resultado... Alguem sabe dizer o que pode ser??!!

Seguem os métodos:

```
public List<Produto> getProdutosPromocionais(boolean promocional, double preco) {
    return ClienteRest.builder().path("produtos").path("promocionais").path(promocional).path(preco).build().listar(Produto.class);
}

    @GET
    @Path("/promocionais/{promocional}/{preco}")
    @AddLinks
    public List<Produto> getProdutosPromocionais(@PathParam("promocional") boolean promocional, @PathParam("preco") double preco) {
        return servico.getProdutosPromocionais(promocional, preco);
    }
```

as query estao corretas, a URL funciona, porem no lado do android retorna NULL..

Comment: Olá, você poderia, por favor, postar o trecho de código em que você efetua a chamada para sua API?

Comment: postei ai em cima

Comment: Quando você faz a mesma mensagem no browser, qual o resultado? Também, como você faz a chamada no android? Tente detalhar mais para tornar o problema reproduzível.

Comment: quando eu chamo no browser, traz a lista certa com os objetos.. no doInBackground() eu tento preencher uma lista usando o metodo serviço, outros metodos funcionam, só este que está retornando null

Comment: ResourceLinks são necessario, caso existam objetos filhos?

Comment: Talvez a chamada que você faz através do *Android* esteja retornando caracteres especiais, o que acaba invalidando todo o retorno.